# Rails controller doesn't recognize model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to build a very simple rails application.

When user submits a form I process some files on the server and display the results.

Clearly, I do not need a database for this. However, I created a model so that I can put all my processing logic in it.

In in the controller, I call the process function in the model. for example

```
# action in controller
def my_action
  MyModel.process(params)
end
```

However, when I run the server and submit the form, rails says MyModel is uninitialized

```
uninitialized constant MyController::MyModel
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you define MyModel? Is it in app/models/my_model.rb as Rails (to put it simply) expects it to be?

Comment: Yes. I actually generated the model.

Comment: Wow. This is so stupid. I went back and checked. my_model.rb is in app/models/my_controller/ instead of app/models/. Thanks for pointing that out.